# What does IDC_STATIC means in a resource.h file?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a simple Win32 project generated by VS 2012. In the `resource.h` file, I saw this:

```
#ifndef IDC_STATIC
#define IDC_STATIC              -1
#endif
```

I found it is been referenced in a couple places in the `resource.rc` file. But I could not understand what it means. Neither did I find reference about it online. Any idea?

Comment: it's related to the STATIC TEXT control (part of the common confrols. You can find more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372076(v=vs.85).aspx), ad then follow the link on that page to CreateWindow/CreateWindowEx for more detnails.

Comment: It's used when you don't need to assign a specific ID to a control because you don't ever want to refer to it programmatically; most often, a static label that never changes and the user doesn't interact with.

Comment: There is no STATIC TEXT control. There is a STATIC control which can display text or images. As Jonathan says, when you don't need to interact with the control at runtime, don't need to receive notifications, the ID is not important. Hence the convention is that -1 is assigned to any controls where runtime interaction is not needed.

Comment: It is declared in WinRes.h.  A pretty obscure SDK header file, just about nobody thinks of #including it.  So, roughly, to reduce the number of support calls they had the resource editor generate it if it isn't defined yet.

Comment: @HansPassant: Nobody includes *winres.h* because it isn't strictly part of the Windows SDK. First line reads: *"// This is a part of the Microsoft Foundation Classes C++ library."* It ships as part of the Windows SDK to reduce the number of support calls. Neither including it nor defining a preprocessor symbol called `IDC_STATIC` are mandatory (while the latter is at least useful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating child controls by calling [`CreateWindowEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx), you have to assign a control ID (through the overloaded *hMenu* parameter). The control ID can later be used to refer to a control, without having to store the dynamically created `HWND` (e.g. when calling [`GetDlgItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481.aspx) or [`GetDlgItemInt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645485.aspx)).

Some controls rarely need to be identified in code. A prominent example is the [Static Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760769.aspx)<sup>1</sup>, that, if defined in a resource script, usually does not need to be referenced in code. You (or the dialog manager) still need to pass a control ID when creating the control, even though you don't use it later on. For those controls you can pass the `IDC_STATIC` control ID, that is defined in a wizard-generated *`Resource.h`* file<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Other examples include the [Icon Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369208.aspx) (a static control with the `SS_ICON` style), the [Line Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369760.aspx) (a static control with the `SS_ETCHEDHORZ` and `SS_SUNKEN` styles), or the [GroupBox Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368766.aspx).*

<sup>2</sup> *This is not a convention of the Windows API<sup>3</sup>. It is strictly a decision made by user code. You could use another ID value, or not define `IDC_STATIC` at all if you want, and use an integer literal in the [LTEXT control statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381021.aspx) instead: `LTEXT "Filename", -1, 10, 10, 100, 100`*

<sup>3</sup> *Granted, the SDK header* `winres.h` *does define the preprocessor symbol `IDC_STATIC` as `(-1)`, so if you do define it in your code, make sure to assign the same value to avoid any confusion.*

Comment: While we're nitpicking with all those footnotes, I feel compelled to point out that the "Icon" and "Line" controls are actually Static controls with different styles.