# GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC)->SetFont(&m_font) throws an exception

Tags: c++, fonts, mfc

I want to change font of static text in MFC dialog And it throw exception.

I have in declaration:

```cpp
CFont m_font;
```

In initdialog:

```cpp
m_font.create(....);
GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC)->SetFont(&m_font);
```

And `CDialog::InitDialog();` throws an exception.

Comment: Check the return value of the `GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC)` call. If that's a null pointer, then you most likely don't have a control with that ID in your dialog box.

Comment: As others have said, give your control a unique ID and use that. Not IDC_STATIC. That is fine for any controls you do not need to access.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does IDC\_STATIC means in a resource.h file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37913963/what-does-idc-static-means-in-a-resource-h-file)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`CWnd::GetDlgItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#getdlgitem)'s return value contains the following:

> A pointer to the given control or child window. **If no control with the integer ID given by the *`nID`* parameter exists, the value is `NULL`.**

Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer results in an access violation exception, probably what you're observing. Make sure your dialog actually contains a control with ID `IDC_STATIC`.

Note that `IDC_STATIC` is a [predefined constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/win32-predefined-symbols) with value `-1`. Its primary purpose is to save you from having to invent an ID when you never intent to access a control by ID (static controls being the primary use case). If you need to access a control by ID you should rather assign it a unique ID, which you probably did already. If you construct the control from a dialog template you'll find the ID in the .rc file that defines the dialog resource.